# Swapping wp_dropdown_categories function with wp_category_checklist

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, categories

I am trying to change a field in a search widget by going into the php files and altering the wp functions. I currently am trying to change a dropdown select box to a check box for categories (parent category atop and child ones below in alphabetical order). The display should be dropdown if possible.

Here is the current dropdown selectbox code:

```
<?php 
                        wp_dropdown_categories( array(
                            'show_option_none'  => '-- '.__( 'Select a location', 'advanced-classifieds-and-directory-pro' ).' --',
                            'option_none_value' => $general_settings['base_location'],
                            'child_of'          => max( 0, $general_settings['base_location'] ),
                            'taxonomy'          => 'acadp_locations',
                            'name'              => 'loc',
                            'id'                => 'acadp-location-search-'.$id,
                            'class'             => 'form-control',
                            'orderby'           => 'name',
                            'selected'          => isset( $_GET['loc'] ) ? (int) $_GET['loc'] : -1,
                            'hierarchical'      => true,
                            'depth'             => 10,
                            'show_count'        => false,
                            'hide_empty'        => false,
                        ) );
                    ?>
```

I am trying to use the builtin wp_category_checklist() funtion.
Can anyone help me out? I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks, 
Luke

Comment: You wrote: '... change a dropdown select box to a check box ... The display should be dropdown...'. Could you reword that to be clearer?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create checklist of the categories instead of a dropdown. I know that I have to use the function wp_category_checklist(); but when I do, it doesnt work. I cant figure out if its because of the array I have there or what. I am lost with it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not working with the default categories but with another taxonomy instead you must not use [`wp_category_checklist()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_category_checklist). Instead you should probably be using the more generic [`wp terms checklist()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_terms_checklist). The signature of this function also differs from the one of [`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories). And the arguments array takes completely different options.

You shlould start with the following code and then adapt it according to your needs:

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php';

wp_terms_checklist( 0, array(
    'taxonomy' => 'acadp_locations',
) );
```

I am not sure if `wp_terms_checklist()` is going to suit all your needs. Maybe you have to write a custom Walker (Start with extending [`Walker_Category_Checklist()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category_checklist/)) to adapt the output to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that; I tried to use that function and just like before, it gave me this message when I tried loading the page: 

Search Listings


Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_terms_checklist() in /home/luker740/public_html/wp-content/plugins/advanced-classifieds-and-directory-pro/public/partials/search/acadp-public-search-form-inline-display.php on line 24

Do you have any idea what the issue can be?

Comment: @LukeRiver The error you get is because the files for these functions are normally only included in the backend. If you already got such an error before when trying `wp_category_checklist()`, you should have written that upfront. I added a line to include the file with the function definition.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that. So I tried plugging this into the code above and it didn't give me the same message but instead gave me a message saying that it timed out. Is the issue because the function is defined within the <?php?> function?

Comment: @LukeRiver I don't know how you plugged this into the code from above, it should be rather replacing it. If you have a timeout you should check your error log, ther must be some kind of loop or something.